# after adding index execution plan showing index is missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am working on sql server 2008..i created index for my Transaction_tbl like this:

```
CREATE INDEX INloc ON transaction_tbl
(
    Locid ASC
)

CREATE INDEX INDtim ON transaction_tbl
(
   DTime ASC
)

CREATE INDEX INStatus ON transaction_tbl
(
    Status ASC
)

CREATE INDEX INDelda ON transaction_tbl
(
     DelDate ASC
)
```

then i checked my execution plan of sql query:but showing index is missing[image]

my query like this:

```
SELECT [transactID]
      ,[TBarcode]
      ,[cmpid]
      ,[Locid]
      ,[PSID]
      ,[PCID]
      ,[PCdID]
      ,[PlateNo]
      ,[vtid]
      ,[Compl]
      ,[self]
      ,[LstTic]
      ,[Gticket]
      ,[Cticket]
      ,[Ecode]
      ,[dtime]
      ,[LICID]
      ,[PAICID]
      ,[Plot]
      ,[mkid]
      ,[mdlid]
      ,[Colid]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[Kticket]
      ,[PAmount]
      ,[Payid]
      ,[Paid]
      ,[Paydate]
      ,[POICID]
      ,[DelDate]
      ,[DelEcode]
      ,[PAICdate]
      ,[KeyRoomDate]
      ,[Status]
  FROM [dbo].[Transaction_tbl] where locid='9'
```

i want to know after adding index why execution plan is showing index is missing if i give my where condition like this:

```
where locid= 9 and status=5 and DelDate='2014-04-05 10:10:00' and dtime='2014-04-05 10:10:00'
```

then not showing index is missing..how come this? if any one know please help me to clarify this..

my index missing details is like this:

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery14.sql - WIN7-PC.Vallett (sa (67))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 71.5363%.
*/

/*
USE [Vallett]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[Transaction_tbl] ([Locid])
INCLUDE ([transactID],[TBarcode],[cmpid],[PSID],[PCID],[PCdID],[PlateNo],[vtid],[Compl],[self],[LstTic],[Gticket],[Cticket],[Ecode],[dtime],[LICID],[PAICID],[Plot],[mkid],[mdlid],[Colid],[Comments],[Kticket],[PAmount],[Payid],[Paid],[Paydate],[POICID],[DelDate],[DelEcode],[PAICdate],[KeyRoomDate],[Status])
GO
*/
```

Comment: What datatype is locid? It seems to be varchar by the look of the query. IF it is `varchar(max)` or `text` you cant index it..

Comment: sir...locid is integer

Comment: We can't see the whole text of the missing index message. Could you pls right-click on the execution plan and chose "missing index details", and update the question with what this produces?

Comment: sir i edited my question with missing index details..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index that SQL Server is suggesting is not the same as you already have - the one you have is on `LocID` alone - while the one SQL Server suggests also **includes** a whole bunch of extra columns so it would become a **covering index**, e.g. your `SELECT` statement could be satisfied from just the index.

With your existing index, the `SELECT` might use the `INloc` index to find a row - **but** to be able to return all those columns you're selecting, it will need to do rather expensive **key lookups** into the actual table data (most likely into the clustered index).

If you added the index suggested by SQL Server, since that index itself would contain all those columns needed, then no key lookups into the data pages would be necessary and thus the operation would be much faster.

So maybe you could check if you **really** need all those columns in your `SELECT` and if not - trim the list of columns.

However: adding this many columns to your `INCLUDE` list is usually not a good idea. I think the index suggestion here is not useful and I'd ignore that.

**Update:** also, if your `SELECT` always contains these four criteria

```
WHERE locid = 9 AND status = 5 AND DelDate='2014-04-05 10:10:00' AND dtime='2014-04-05 10:10:00'
```

then maybe you could try to have a single index that contains all four columns:

```
CREATE INDEX LocStatusDates 
ON transaction_tbl(Locid, Status, DelDate, dtime)
```

Comment: sir what i can do this situation??

Comment: @user3262364: as I said: either just ignore that suggested index, or try to limit your column list in the `SELECT` so that this covering index that SQL Server suggests is more manageable

Comment: at least how much column i can give?? and instead of creating index like that,,i can create index like this:CREATE INDEX IX_TRANSACTION ON transaction_tbl
(
    Locid ASC, DTime ASC, Status ASC, DelDate ASC
)..this will effect?

Comment: if i give index like this..this will affect my insertion,deletion ,updation?

Comment: @user3262364: **every** index will affect **all** operations, yes

Comment: ok,,i want know this will decrease my insertion or updation speed?

Comment: @user3262364: as I said : **EVERY** index will have some impact on your speed. Having an index is **ALWAYS** a trade-off between (hopefully) speeding up `SELECT` queries and taking a bit of overhead for index maintenance. But if this new index works, then you can drop the four other indices and most likely have a benefit all around

Comment: ok,,sir,,some of the my select statement not contains this four criteria..some query only where locid=5 and some query only where status=5..

Comment: if i create index what you suggested then it will affect at any select criteria right?

Comment: Your index can be used if your criteria include the **N left-most** columns in the index. It will **NOT** be useful if your `WHERE` clause only contains `Status = ...`

Comment: i didnt get you last commend:if your criteria include the N left-most columns in the index,,why it wont be use full if my WHERE clause only contains Status = ...

Comment: @user3262364: your index will be used if you specify **all 4** criteria - or the 3 left-most (`locid, status, deldate`) - or the 2 left-most (`locid, status`) or the 1 left-most (`locid`) - but the index **CANNOT** be used for just `Status` or just `deldate` or (`status`, `deldate`)